# How to get updated wrapper after axios call

Tags: react-native, jestjs, axios, react-hooks, enzyme

I have a function that looks like the following and I am trying to test the rowDoubleClicked function.
I mock the axios resolved value and I can see that the getAccountData function is being covered which should mean the update to dataArray.isLoading would be false.

however in my test when I debug the wrapper. It always hits the if statement that renders the loading div instead of the grid component and Im trying to figure out how to make it render the grid so that i can call the rowDoubleClicked function.

I've tried updating the wrapper, but it stays the same.
I've also tried doing an awat waitForElement on the  component but it just gets timed out

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  let grid;
  const dataArray = {
    errorText: '',
    rowData: '',
    isLoading: true,
  };
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  if (undefined !== data) {
    dataArray.errorText = data.errorText;
    dataArray.isLoading = data.isLoading;
    dataArray.rowData = data.rowData;
  }

  const setShow = props.functions;
  const getAccountData = async () => {
    await axios
      .get(props.endpoint)
      .then((result) => {
        dataArray.rowData = result;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dataArray.errorText = error;
      });
    dataArray.isLoading = false;
    setData(dataArray);
  };
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const rowDoubleClicked = () => {
    //some action
  };

  if (dataArray.errorText !== '') {
    grid = (
      <div>
        <p>Error</p>
      </div>
    );
  } else if (dataArray.isLoading) {
    getAccountData();
    grid = (
      <div className="loading">
        <p>Loading</p>
      </div>
    );
  } else if (dataArray.rowData !== '') {
    grid = <Grid handleRowDoubleClicked={rowDoubleClicked} />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal visible={props.show} closable onCancel={handleClose}>
        <div>{grid}</div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

MyComponentView

```
import React from 'react'
import MyComponent from ''

const MyComponentView = (props) => {
 
  const [select, setSelect] = React.useState('')
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false)
  const [selectedSearchBy, setSearchBy] = React.useState('')
  const [selectedValue, setSearchByValue] = React.useState('')

  const handleSearchIconClick = () => {
    setShow(true)
  }
 
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setSearchBy(e.selectedOptionVal)
    setSearchByValue(e.value)
  }

 
  return (
    <div>
        <form
          action={`${endpoint`}
          method='post'
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
          <input type='hidden' id='searchBy' name='searchBy' value={selectedSearchBy} />
          <input type='hidden' id='searchValue' name='searchValue' value={selectedValue} />
          <Button data-testid='accessButton' id='accessButton' block color='primary'>
          Search
          </Button>
        </form>
        {show && (
          <MyComponent
            show
            functions={setShow}
            onModalApplyClick={handleApply}
            endpoint={endpoint}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyComponentView
```

here is my current test

```js
it('performs double click on grid', async () => {
  let wrapper;
  let grid;
  axios.get.mockResolvedValue(dataJSON);
  wrapper = mount(
    <MyComponent {...props} show>
      <Modal>
        <Grid {...gridProps} />
      </Modal>
    </MyComponent>
  );
  grid = wrapper.find(Grid);
  wrapper.update();
  await waitForElement(() => expect(grid).toBeTruthy());
  grid.invoke('handleRowDoubleClicked')();
  await act(() => Promise.resolve());
});
```

Comment: Please post your component's render logic.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like your `axios.get.mockResolvedValue` is not working as intended. In such situations, I, personally, just use `axios-mock-adapter`.

Also, seems like `waitForElement` has been deprecated. How about a simple `setTimeout` with jest's `done()`?

```
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

it('...', (done) => {
    const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
    mock.onPost().reply(200, dataJSON);

    //your test's logic

    setTimeout(() => {
        expect(grid).toBeTruthy();
    }, 1000);  //or any reasonable delay
});
```